# angular 4 scrolling event

Tags: javascript, angular, scroll

I'm quite lost in scroll event handling.

I want to disable scrolling; when the user hits the scroll wheel x times I want the page to scroll down (with some animation) down to a certain element. I was able to add the HostListener but I didn't get any further.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    public onScrollEvent(event) {
}
```

but the first issue is that **event.preventDefault()** or **event.stopPropagation()** are not working.
I tried something like

```
event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

and when my counter hits a certain number call

```
event.target.scrollingElement.scrollTop = 1080;
```

But this was a mess! :).

I also didn't find any scrolling manual on angular official site.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the css styles itself.

```
body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: then the onScrolEvent method doesn't get called at all. I'm using this in a component wrapped in router-outlet - does it change something?

Comment: what is that your exact scenario?

Comment: I have APP component, inside of it, there's top-menu component and router-outlet. Of my components should work like I described above. The scrolling should be disabled and when (for example) user hits the wheel for the third time it should move down (scroll down) to some element (taking the full height of the page) - basically like a slideshow. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the event on the @HostListener decoration HAS to match with the name of the argument passed to the onScrollEvent method. It has to be literally the same, try with:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
public onScrollEvent($event){/*handler operations here...*/}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
onScroll(event) {
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, 0);
}
```

and when your counter hits a certain number call:

```
window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, 1000);
```